# One-To-Many Entity Framework 5 Update with code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

I have ONE entity that i want to update without updating its List of MANY entity. Im using Code-First But i cant get it to work... 
Im using Ninject and everything is working except my update...

//Entities

```
public class A
{
public int AId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class B
{
public int BId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual List<A>ListOfAs { get; set; }
}
```

//Interface

```
private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

public IQueryable<B> Bs
        {
            get { return context.B; }
        }

        public void SaveBs(B b)
    {
        if (b.Id== 0)
        {
            context.B.Add(b);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        *//here i wanna call: 
        context.Entity(b).State = EntityState.Modified;
        BUT VS dont let me... I probably missing something out...*

        context.SaveChanges();
```

the Save method is working when i want to just add a new object to my database. But the update wont change anything...

I would appricate if anyone could tell me what im missing out...

/Thx J

Answer (score 2):

Use The Following Criteria, This work for me

```
public BuyerInformation Update(BuyerInformation objBuyerInformation)
    {
        context.BuyerInformation.Attach(objBuyerInformation);
        context.Entry(objBuyerInformation).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();

        return objBuyerInformation;
    }
```

Comment: `context.BuyerInformation.Attach(objBuyerInformation);` isn't actually needed. It's kind of weird but it works without it. I was surprised too :)

Comment: Have any explanation about that. Please describe.

Comment: I don't know why. It just works without it. This tutorial also backs me: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
if (b.Id== 0)
    {
        context.B.Add(b);
    }
else
   {
       context.B.Attach(b);
   }
   context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: no that is not working... still no update. Thx for ur quick answer tho.

Comment: Im getting the updated Object back, but the updates doesn't go through to my database. The Entity cant save the changes...

Comment: nop. It just dont get updated... i got a temp var (in my view) that writes out the new name of the object and x.Name gets updated to the new name... I cant understand why i cant use "EntityState.Modified".